# AUCTeX: Making new environments available for completion after C-c C-e

Tags: auctex

I have defined a new environment, `argument`. I would now like to include "argument" as one of the possible completions after hitting <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>, and upon selecting it, be prompted for an optional argument.

Unfortunately, I cannot even get to the first of these two steps, adding "argument" as one of the possible completions, never mind being prompted.

I've added the following into my `.emacs` file, minimally adapting the example from the manual.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (LaTeX-add-environments
       '("argument" LaTeX-env-label))))
```

But after re-loading the configuration file, I hit <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> and I don't get "argument" as one of the options.

Comment: How do you define your new environment `argument`, with `\newenvironment` in the preamble of your .tex file?

Comment: @ArashEsbati: Just about: I've got it in a style file that I load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual practice for getting completion for hand written LaTeX packages is to write a corresponding AUCTeX style file.  Suppose your LaTeX file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{myenvs}

\begin{document}
\begin{argument}[Optional argument}
  Content
\end{argument}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

And you have your environment `argument` defined in `myenvs.sty`.  The AUCTeX style `myenvs.el` should look like this:

```el
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "myenvs"
 (lambda ()
   (LaTeX-add-environments
    '("argument" [ "argument" ])))
 TeX-dialect)
```

Save this file in a directory which is stored in the variable `TeX-style-private`, e.g. something like this in your init file or use `customize`:

```el
(setq TeX-style-private (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/auctex-styles"))
```

Make sure you also have `TeX-parse-self` to  `t`.  Now restart Emacs and open your .tex file again.